# How to fix token generate in REST API call?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, loopback

I'm using angular 7 with loopback for API. But I'm testing one sample code there is have **token** and **token/generate-token** i don't know how to generate or how to access except this token. Please help me guys.

**API function**

```
  login(loginPayload) : Observable<ApiResponse> {
     return this.http.post<ApiResponse>('http://localhost:3000/' +'token/generate-token', loginPayload);
  }
```

when I tried this there is an error which shows **404**.

```
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/token/generate-token: 404 Not Found"
```

​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 404
​
statusText: "Not Found"
​
url: "http://localhost:3000/token/generate-token"

Comment: well, a `404` means there's no such API i.e. `token/generate-token` or either you have to spin up your server

Comment: Are you sure API `http://localhost:3000/token/generate-token` exist?!!

Comment: you should be sure about API url and parameters are correct. You can test the request via postman.

Comment: Yes it's exist but without this one I cannot access the value for login purpose

Comment: Can anyone explain what is **token/generate-token** ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm wrongly called API that's why I can't generate the token